# Why are some foreign functions statically linked while others are dynamically linked?

Tags: haskell, libgit2

I'm working on a program that needs to manipulate git repositories. I've decided to use libgit2. Unfortunately, the haskell bindings for it are several years out of date and lack several functions that I require. Because of this I've decided to write the portions that use libgit2 in C and call them through the FFI. For demonstration purposes one of them is called git_update_repo.

git_update_repo works perfectly when used in a pure C program, however when it's called from haskell an assertion fails indicating that the libgit2 global init function, git_libgit2_init, hasn't been called. But, git_libgit2_init is called by git_update_repo. And if I use gdb I can see that git_libgit2_init is indeed called and reports that the initialization has been successful.

I've used nm to examine the executables and found something interesting. In a pure C executable, all the libgit2 functions are dynamically linked (as expected). However, in my haskell executable, git_libgit2_init is dynamically linked, while the rest of the libgit2 functions are statically linked. I'm certain that this mismatch is the cause of my issue.

So why do certain functions get linked dynamically and others statically? How can I change this?

The relevant settings in my .cabal file are

```
  cc-options: -g
  c-sources:
      src/git-bindings.c
  extra-libraries:
      git2
```

Comment: Alternative:  Try [hlibgit2](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hlibgit2) or [gitlib](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gitlib)

Comment: The latest version of hlibgit2 provides bindings to libgit2 version 0.18.0 which, as I said in my post, is several years out of date and lacks the functions that I need.

Comment: Yes, but the [gitlib](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gitlib) says “Several different backends are available.”  Maybe there is one which satifies your needs.

Comment: you should be able to get the actual linking command with adding "-v" to ghc command line. That would be very helpful to answer your question.

Comment: Could you have some indirect dependency on the libgit2? So that you depend on another C library, which depends on it? This could explain mismatched linking.

Comment: Or, maybe, you use a haskell binding in same program.